# Cannot scroll outer listview when scroll end of the inner listview

Tags: flutter

I have nested list view with vertical scroll. I am able to scroll outer and inner list view. But when the inner list view scrolls to the end of its list item, I could not scroll the outer list view, though there are some list items present after the inner list view.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Text(
          'Hello, World!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
        Text(
          'Hello, World!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: ListView(
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  child: Text(
                    'Hello, inner World!',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  child: Text(
                    'Hello, inner World!',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
              Text(
                'Hello, inner World!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          'Hello, World!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
        Text(
          'Hello, World!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In the above sample, I am able to scroll the inner list view, but could not see the last list item from outer list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Primary](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/primary.html) property in the `ListView`

In your case you need to add `primary: false` in your inner `ListView` properties.

```
ListView(primary: false, childeren : [])
```